# converting iOS10 keyboard app to iMessage App

Tags: swift3, xcode8, imessage-extension

Do you know of a "simple" way to convert an existing keyboard app in IOS10 to be also an iMessage App?
I have a containing app and an extension keyboard as such it is perfect for iMEssage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about how simple, but creating a new target for you app, to have an iMessage App Extension will be a good start. There's no one-to-one mapping, but it should be straightforward.

Difficult to say for sure without knowing more about the code, or what the keyboard app does. Check out [this tutorial](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/ios-10-day-by-day-day-1-messages) to get started..

Comment: Thanks. I wonder if you have an existing keyboard why can't you incorporate it into the iMEssage App quickly without rebuilding your app from the start (almost)...

Comment: I am having the same issue as Eran is facing. I have not yet made any decision of making an app from scratch and add upload its extension to iMessage in the same App created on appstore which is being used by user  with OS less than 10

Comment: Hi Lion, any progress?